# Is it possible to specify the region on camera and get only image that belongs to that area in ios?

Tags: ios, camera, crop

I want to place the rectangle on the camera and drag to particular place and then want to get the cropped image of that particular rectangular area and save to photo album.

Please suggest me the procedure to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best site for custom UIImagePickerController.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UIImagePickerController

You can find and get custom UIImagePickerController as you want.